# OECD data extraction Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to extract OECD data using web.DataReader, however it gives me just NA values regardless of the data set. How can I fix this problem?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas_datareader import wb
import datetime


series = 'ALFS_SUMTAB'
source = 'oecd'
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)

df_oecd = web.DataReader(series, data_source = source, start = start, end = end)
print(df_oecd)
Country       Australia  ... European Union – 27 countries (from 01/02/2020)
Subject    Labour force  ...                     Unemployment males , (‘000)
Frequency        Annual  ...                                          Annual
Time                     ...                                                
2015-01-01          NaN  ...                                             NaN
2016-01-01          NaN  ...                                             NaN
2017-01-01          NaN  ...                                             NaN
2018-01-01          NaN  ...                                             NaN
2019-01-01          NaN  ...                                             NaN

[5 rows x 1305 columns]
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134701/extracting-data-from-pandas-multiindex-dataframe

Comment: @kiyis_stats answered you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, not all cells are empty. If you reduce the amount of data and specify to print all rows and columns, then using the example of Australia, you can see this.

```
print(df_oecd[['Australia']])
```

I tried the 'pandasdmx' library, for this task and the values there are correct (I checked a few in Australia). And there are no empty values. This library provides a wealth of data on the subject, but it's somewhat complex, at least for me. And the terms 'SUBJECT' print the data in abbreviations.

OECD [data](https://stats.oecd.org/viewhtml.aspx?datasetcode=ALFS_SUMTAB&lang=en)

Decryption I found [here](https://db.nomics.world/OECD/ALFS_SUMTAB/AUS.YGFE06L1_ST.A)

Description of the library [pandasdmx](https://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0/)

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasdmx as sdmx
import pandas_datareader.data as web


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)#print everything rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)#print everything columns

series = 'ALFS_SUMTAB'
source = 'oecd'
start = '2015-01-01'
end = '2019-01-01'

df_oecd = web.DataReader(series, data_source = source, start = start, end = end)
print(df_oecd[['Australia']])

oecd = sdmx.Request('OECD')
params = dict(startPeriod=start, endPeriod=end)
data_msg = oecd.data('ALFS_SUMTAB', key='all', params=params)
data = data_msg.data[0]
df = sdmx.to_pandas(data).unstack() #turn data into a dataframe
print(df)
```

Output df

```
TIME_PERIOD                                 2015           2016  \
LOCATION  SUBJECT       FREQUENCY                                 
AUS       YGFE06L1_ST   A             350.768500     342.610100   
          YGFE06P2_ST   A               6.076174       5.779326   
          YGFE07L1_ST   A            5790.826000    5911.280000   
          YGFE08L1_ST   A            5439.183000    5569.702000   
          YGFE08PE_ST   A              46.226920      46.518510   
          YGFE22P1_ST   A               8.189193       8.175810   
          YGMA06L1_ST   A             403.500800     381.139800   
          YGMA06P2_ST   A               6.039518       5.649940   
          YGMA07L1_ST   A            6733.703000    6786.857000   
          YGMA08L1_ST   A            6327.085000    6403.385000   
          YGMA08PE_ST   A              53.773080      53.481490   
          YGMA22P1_ST   A              12.132350      11.719000
```

---